# Debian Linux root disk getting full, need to transfer /var folder to another disk

Tags: linux, debian, mount, disk, fdisk

One of the disks got out of space, however other disk is nearly empty. Need suggestions how to transfer biggest folder(`/var`) to the other disk and mount at `/var`. For now `/var` folder was in `/` partition. Got 90GB unallocated space at `/dev/sdb`. It's a vmware virtual machine.

```
$df -H result

Filesystem                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                   22G   20G  711M  97% /
udev                                     11M     0   11M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                   425M  398k  425M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a8db5cdb-96f3-4497-9   22G   20G  711M  97% /
tmpfs                                   5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                   850M     0  850M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sdb1                                11G  980M  8.9G  11% /home

$fdisk -l result

Disk /dev/sda: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2610 cylinders, total 41943040 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c0f7f

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      194559       96256   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2   *      194560    41940991    20873216   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders, total 209715200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002dc8d

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    20482047    10240000   83  Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

**Be warned**, if no data can be lost you should either start the system `init 1` as suggested by type_outcast or start with a live USB system to do the next process.

Since you already have a partition on sdb, if you want to use the whole partition just check if the filesystem is created. Otherwise create it yourself (`mkfs`).

Once created mount both partitions

```
mkdir /mnt/orig
mkdir /mnt/dest

mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/dest
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/orig
```

and `rsync` your /var to /mnt.

`rsync -av /mnt/orit/var/* /mnt/dest/`

Once done identify your partitions UUID with `blkid` and modify your /mnt/orig/etc/fstab creating a new line for your /var pointing to the UUID of your new /var partition.

`UUID=UUID_returned_by_blkid    /var    ext4    defaults      2 2`

Comment: `/var` on a typical Debian system will contain many open files, including databases that may be corrupted, block specials, and in general should not be moved while in multi-user mode. Suggest going to `init 1` or expanding on your "start system with another one" suggestion, as that part of your answer is easy to overlook as it is currently written.

Comment: OK, it's been modified. Hope it is more visible and clearer now. Thanks @type_outcast

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to physically move the files to the new partition, and then re-create an empty /var for the mount point, and then `mount /dev/sdb1 /var`. (And, for permanent effect, add a line to `/etc/fstab` such as the following):

```
/dev/sdb1   /var    ext4    rw  0   1
```

However, the "physically move files to the new partition" step bears more explanation. On a typical Debian system, `/var` is likely to contain many open files, databases, and special nodes (sockets and the like).

First, make the edit to `/etc/fstab` described above. Then, you need to put your system into single-user mode to stop the activity that normally goes on in `/var`.

```
sudo init 1
```

Then you can mount /var in a new temporary location and copy the contents of `/var` to it:

```
mkdir /mnt/var
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/var  # Temporary mount

cd /var
cp . -ax /mnt/var # Copy /var contents to new partition

cd /
mv /var /var.old  # Backup old /var in case anything goes wrong
umount /mnt/var   # We are done with that for now
reboot
```

Once the system reboots, `/var` should automatically be mounted in its proper location, with all of your files preserved. Once you are happy with everything, you can `rm -Rf /var.old` to remove the backup copy.

Comment: /dev/sdb1 is /home mount, I created new partition /dev/sdb2 from unallocated space and then your guide worked with the new /dev/sdb2 partition. Thanks!